# Stackdriver - How to fetch logs of a kubernetes pod running on Google Cloud using REST APIs?

Tags: rest, kubernetes, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

My application is deployed on a Kubernetes Cluster that runs on Google Cloud. I want to fetch logs written by my application using [Stackdriver's REST APIs for logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/logs/list).

From the above documentation page and [this example](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/logging/usage.html#retrieving-log-entries), it seems that I can only list logs of a project, organization, billing account or folder.

I want to know if there are any REST APIs using which I can fetch logs of:

- A pod in a Kubernetes Cluster running on Google Cloud
- A VM instance running on Google Cloud

Comment: Kubernetes itself has [an extensive REST API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-overview/).

Answer (score 1):

you need to request per [MonitoredResource](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/MonitoredResource), which permits instance names and alike... for GCE that would be `gce_instance` while for GKE it would be `container`. individual pods of a cluster can be filtered by their `cluster_name` & `pod_id`; the documentation for [resource-list](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/v2/resource-list) describes it:

> **container** (GKE Container) A Google Container Engine (GKE) container instance.
>
> **project_id**: The identifier of the GCP project associated with this resource, such as "my-project".
>
> **cluster_name**: An immutable name for the cluster the container is running in.
>
> **namespace_id**: Immutable ID of the cluster namespace the container is running in.
>
> **instance_id**: Immutable ID of the GCE instance the container is running in.
>
> **pod_id**: Immutable ID of the pod the container is running in.
>
> **container_name**: Immutable name of the container.
>
> **zone**: The GCE zone in which the instance is running.